# Why is the estimate (out of Stream Aggregate) so low?

Tags: sql-server-2017, statistics, index-statistics

I have a table like this:

```
create TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
TMyTableID bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
LogArgumentID bigint NOT null,
LogID bigint NOT NULL,
LogTextID int NOT NULL,
FloatValue float NULL,
Filler varchar(500) null,
EXTExtractJobID bigint not null
) ON Standard
WITH
(
DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE
)
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_LogID_LogArgumentID ON dbo.MyTable (LogID, LogArgumentID, TMyTableID DESC) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON Standard
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (LogArgumentID) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON Standard
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EXTExtractJobID ON dbo.MyTable (EXTExtractJobID, LogArgumentID) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON Standard
GO
```

with about 75 billion rows.
When I run a query similar to this:

```
select logid, max(case when logTextID =1 then floatvalue end) as MaxFloatValue
from  dbo.MyTable as M
where TMyTableID > cast(12300000000 as bigint)
and   TMyTableID > cast(12350000000 as bigint)
group by M.logid
```

I get a plan like this:
[image: execution plan from Plan Explorer]

The estimates out of the Clustered Index Seek is about right, but the estimate from the Stream Aggregate is 100x off the real data.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the stats was bad, because the sample size was so small.

If I run:

```
SELECT o.name as tablename, s.name as statsname, s.stats_id, sp.object_id, sp.stats_id, sp.step_number, sp.range_high_key, cast(sp.range_rows as bigint) as range_rows, cast(sp.equal_rows as bigint) as equal_rows, cast(sp.distinct_range_rows as bigint) as distinct_range_rows
, cast(sp.average_range_rows as decimal(19,1)) as average_range_rows
from sys.stats AS s
INNER JOIN sys.objects o on o.object_id = s.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch on sch.schema_id = o.schema_id
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_histogram(s.object_id, s.stats_id) AS sp
where o.name ='mytable'
and s.name='ix_LogID_ArgumentID'
```

I get a result set that look like this:
[image: first result from stats]

Where I run

```
update statistics dbo.mytable ix_LogID_LogArgumentID 
with sample 10 percent, PERSIST_SAMPLE_PERCENT = on, norecompute
```

I get a much better result:
[image: second result set from stats]

You can see that the Equal_rows and Average_Range_Rows are much nearer to the truth (if you know your data).

So in the future I'll be setting the **PERSIST_SAMPLE_PERCENT** whenever **0.02 percent** is not enough to give a true picture of the data.
But I'll also consider setting **norecompute**, so that Auto-update of statistics do not occur, as even *1 percent* of big tables can take hours to update.

If you rebuild your indexes, then remember to be on one of the latest CUs, otherwise SQL Server may forget your desired sample percent.